# Ext4-extended-linuxswap

Tags: filesystem, files

I have just installed GPARTED on Ubuntu.

I should only have 1 partition however it lists it as:

Partition:       File System    Mount Point    Size

/dev/sda1       ext4            /               919.79 Gib 
/dev/sda2       extended                         11.72 Gib 
    /dev/sda5   linux-swap                       11.72 GIb

The Sda1 makes sense, but what is the sda2 and extended mean? can I delete this an make 1 file system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three types of partitions.
1. Primary
2. Extended
3. Logical

There can only be 4 primary partitions on a hard drive. When one wants to create more than 4 partitions, an extended partition is created and then more logical partitions are created inside the extended partition. So extended partition is like a container which contains logical partitions in it. For more on partitions go to http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/structPartitions-c.html

In your HDs configuration sda1 is a primary partition, sda2 is just an extended partition and sda5 is a logical partition which is inside sda2 and occupies all the space of sda2. You can see that sda2 and sda5 have exactly the same space. So basically there are just 2 useable partitions i.e sda1 and sda5.

Sda5 is linux swap space. In linux, a partition is reserved as swap space. Swap space is used to extend your ram using some space on your hard disk. So if you have just 64 MB ram and you are able to run binaries or programs larger than 64 MB, it is because your some space on your HD is being used to extend your ram. When some part of program is not being use at the moment it is swapped out of ram in to the swap space. When program needs that part, it is swaped back in to the ram. If you want to know more you can google for virtual memory and you will find a lot of info about it.

DO NOT delete these partitions as Linux needs swap space to run.

Answer (score -1):

sda1 is usually where your files and linux operating system files are kept. (dev/sda1)

I'm not entirely sure what the Extended is for, I think this mounts as a separate drive... which on Ubuntu will say 11.72GB File system.

Your sda5 (dev/sda5) is your linux swap. The swap is used when sda1 is full and the system needs to write something temporary to disk. A Linux swap isn't really needed, it just helps when your HDD is full.